# Angular 2 http get not working, never reaches the server

Tags: web-services, http, angular, web

I am using a working project of Angular 2 from a Pluralsight course as a reference to make my first app.

This exisiting app fetchs the data from a Json file.

```
private _productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

If I modify the url to my own web service that runs locally "http://localhost:53785/api/Session" and run the angular 2 app, It never reaches the breakpoint that I set in my web service and I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" error.

In the console I get:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" 
Response
_body
:
""
headers
:
Headers
ok
:
false
status
:
500
statusText
:
"Internal Server Error"
type
:
2
url
:
"http://localhost:53785/api/Session"
**proto**
:
Body

Does anyone know why cant I reach my web service?

Thanks

Comment: It's reaching the web server - which is replying with a 500 error - so something is failing someplace on the server before wherever you've placed your breakpoint.

Comment: as @cartant mentioned above you only get the 500 error if it reached your server, the fail might have occurred before the call reached your application. Also you method is returning an observable, I think you are supposed to subscribe to the observable so that it can fetch data

Comment: Thanks, but I am surprised it doesn't work because using swagger my web service works fine, and also I consume data from an android app and everything works fine

Comment: What do you get for a GET request to your "http://localhost:53785/api/Session" using PostMan for example?

Comment: Works perfect with postman

Comment: That url looks suspicious... should it not begin with `http://....` even though you are running it locally.